# terminal on ubuntu can not open

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

I uninstalled accidentally python3.10 using rm -rf python3.10 in /usr/bin my terminal is not working anymore
but can access through VSCode but it say [image]
any suggestion? thank you in advanced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because /usr/bin/python3 is a soft link to /usr/bin/python3.10 which is the main binary that runs python3 on your machine.
This should help :

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 May 31 13:02 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.10
```

You might need to install python again to get the binary.
If you have different version of python available that you want to use, create link to it like this:

`ln -s file1 link1`
which would be in case you have python3.10 re/installed

```
ln -s /usr/bin/python3.10 /usr/bin/python3
```

Considering you deleted python3.10 binary by mistake!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this could also help to somebody, because I got the similar issue, and I solved it on bizarre way: 
In your Ubuntu open settings and go to ***Language and Region*** and switch language to some other (for example Canadian English) and restart VM and terminal will work.
If you try to back it to previous language, you also could do it, it worked also for me.

Comment: Two different issues.